# каталог с механикой push-уведомлений

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня в игре есть магазин,в котором эмблемы купленных предметов удаляются.Мне нужно что бы после покупки чего-либо рядом расположенные эмблемы передвинулись к освобожденному месту,как push-уведомления.Как это сделать?

Comment: Компоновку элементов можно автоматизировать (но смещение будет без анимации, т.е. сразу переместится в другую ячейку) компонентами **GridLayoutGroup**, **Vertical(Horizontal)LayoutGroup**

Comment: Касаемо уведомлений, вам нужно ознакомиться с паттерном `Observer`.